# Powershell adding values together

Tags: arrays, powershell, addition, powershell-2.0

Here is my code:

```
clear-host

function isNumeric ($x) {
try {
    0 + $x | Out-Null
    return $true
} catch {
    return $false
}
}

function output-file ($ave, $high, $low, $date)
{
write-output "Programer: Oday Sawaqed"
write-output "Class: CIS 124"
write-output "PowerShell Assignmnent"
write-output ""
Write-output ""
write-output " Current Date                    Average               Highest                        Lowest"
write-output " $date                $ave                   $high                 $low "
}


$array = @()
$hold
$n = 1

do {
$hold = read-host "number $n"
if (isNumeric $hold -eq $true){
if (999 -ne $hold) {
$array += $hold
$n = $n + 1
}
else
{
clear-host
write-host "Thank you."
write-host "The numbers you entered are:" $array
write-host "Please select a file name to save the output:"
$fileName = Read-host

$date = get-date -format "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"
$array = $array | Sort-Object 
$ave = 
$high = $array | Select-Object -last 1
$low = $array | Select-Object -first 1

output-file $ave $high $low $date | Out-File c:\$fileName.txt
}
}
else {
write-host "Please enter a numeric value"
}
}
while (999 -ne $hold)
```

Now the code works perfectly, i just can't figure out how to add up the values in my array to calculate the average. can someone please help me or give me  a hint!
i know that i need to add the values together and then divide be $n, i just don't know how to add the values.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To compute average you can use `Measure-Object` Cmdlet:

```
($array | Measure-Object -Average).average
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)
i knew you can do it this way except that i was put .ave instead of .average and thats why it never worked . I'm still a noob.
but yeah, thank you!

Comment: +1, I was looking for how to sum an array. And you reminded me that measure-object would also do many of the maths type tasks.

Answer (score 3):

One way I [found](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sum_and_product_of_an_array#PowerShell) to do the addition would be something like this:

```
$sum = $array -join '+'
Invoke-Expression $sum
```

Your output of `$sum` is simply going to add the "+" and then `invoke-expression` will actually do the math for you. So your output would look something like:

```
$sum
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9
Invoke-Expression $sum
45
```

Comment: What about the first method listed in the link which uses "measure-object" to calculate the sum?

Comment: Mike Shepard, you are correct.
User847990, thanks, that just happened to be what I was looking for!
10 years later and this is still findable, I LOVE THIS SITE!